# jQuery each function and getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, video

I'm building a CMS site for a client who'll be uploading videos. I'm trying to build a custom progress bar for each video too, I've done this before but there was only one video present so I could use a `getElementByID` to call each video, but as there's going to be multiple videos per page I tried to call an `each` function and find each element by it's class within it's parent container.

You can see my codepen here: https://codepen.io/neal_fletcher/pen/JJzbYP

As you can see though the progress bar isn't moving when the video plays (as it should), there's only one video here but there will be multiple videos so I CANT use a function that relies on ID's of each element.

My jQuery markup below too:

```
window.onload = function() {
  $(".video-wrap").each(function() {
    var slideshowVideo = document.getElementsByClassName("homepage-video");

    var slideshowSeek = document.getElementsByClassName("seek-bar");

    slideshowSeek.addEventListener("change", function() {
      // Calculate the new time
      var time = slideshowVideo.duration * (slideshowSeek.value / 100);

      // Update the video time
      slideshowVideo.currentTime = time;
    });
  });
```

Any suggestions on the best solution for this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: As an aside... I'd always used querySelector/querySelectorAll. Much more useful...

Answer (score 0):

Working code

```
  window.onload = function() { 
  $(".video-wrap").each(function() {
    var slideshowVideo = document.getElementsByClassName("homepage-video");

    var slideshowSeek = document.getElementsByClassName("seek-bar");

    slideshowSeek[0].addEventListener("change", function() {
      // Calculate the new time

      var time = slideshowVideo.video.duration * (slideshowSeek[0].value / 100);

      // Update the video time
      slideshowVideo.video.currentTime = time;
    });

 slideshowVideo.video.addEventListener('timeupdate', function(video){
    slideshowSeek[0].value = slideshowVideo.video.currentTime * 100 / slideshowVideo.video.duration;
 }, false);

  });

}
```

check below pen
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjvRXP?editors=0110

Comment: I've just tried the codepen, doesn't seem to be working though? The progress bar isn't progressing when the video plays?

Comment: Check updated codepen. It is working now.https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qjvRXP?editors=0110